# Rigidity lemma(weaker version)

Tags: complex-geometry, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and let $Y \& Z$ be complex manifolds. Suppose $f: X \times Y \rightarrow Z$ is holomorphic and $f(X; y_0) = z_0$. Then, there is a holomorphic map $g: Y \rightarrow Z$ such that f factors

[image: commutative diagram]

I tried it this way:
From the above diagram it follows that,
$g(y):=f(x_0,y)$

$f(x,y_0)=f(x',y_0) \hspace{1 cm} \forall x,x' \in X$

$\implies f(x,y)=f(x',y) \hspace{1 cm} \forall x,x' \in X, y \in Y$

for any open set $U \subset Z$, we have $\pi_y(f^{-1}(U^\complement))$ is a closed map.(since $X$ is compact, $\pi_y$ is a proper map \& proper maps are closed). So, g is continuous.

To prove holomorphic one need to choose coordinate chats for $X \times Y$ and charts for X which is induced by the map $\pi$.

But, my instructor said there is something wrong in the proof. I didn't get it.

Please help me out!

Comment: Is the condition $f(X,y_0)=z_0$ holds for some $y_0$ or for all$y_0$?

Comment: @JohnMa The condition is only for one $y_0$ to start with.

Comment: @JohnMa Oh yes, but I assumed it for all $y_0$ in my solution approach. But still I didn't understand, how things goes around